# Blazor Server - how to configure for on-premises ADFS Security?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, authorization, adfs, blazor-server-side

I have an existing Blazor (Server) app addressing .NET Core 3.1 preview 2.

I need to retrospectively add on-prem ADFS (not Azure) security.  I've been trying to follow Microsoft's [Authenticate users with WS-Federation in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/ws-federation?view=aspnetcore-3.1#add-ws-federation-as-an-external-login-provider-for-aspnet-core-identity) and it's stubbornly ignoring the security.  The article is of course written for ASP.NET, not Blazor...

What I've done so far is:

```
public static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddWsFederation(options =>
        {
            options.MetadataAddress = "https://adfs.Server.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml";
            options.Wtrealm = "https://localhost:44323/";
        });

    services.AddAuthorization();

    services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddServerSideBlazor();

    ....
```

**One thing of concern** - the DB currently has tables in it supporting an earlier authentication pattern (membership?) (used by the application we're re-writing).  It has the tables [AspNetRoles] [AspNetUserClaims] [AspNetUserLogins] [AspNetUserRoles] and [AspNetUsers].  Will any of this get overwritten?

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }    

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (optionsBuilder != null)
        {
            if (optionsBuilder.IsConfigured == false)
            {
                IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
                    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Startup.CurrentEnvironment}.json")
                    .Build();

                optionsBuilder
                    .UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDatabase"), 
                           providerOptions => providerOptions.CommandTimeout(60));
            }
        }

        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }
}
```

In the Configure method, I've added (though I'm not clear on whether I needed to):

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

In the App.razor, I have:

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            @*<RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />*@
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />>
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

And in one of my razor pages (MyPage.razor), I've got:

```
@page "/myRoute"    
@attribute [Authorize]
```

When I browse to the page with the Autorize attribute, I get the message:

> Not authorized

So it's not calling out to my ADFS server.  Shouldn't it just do this automatically - the user shouldn't have to click a "log me in" button.

I've referenced the following NuGet packages:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.WsFederation" Version="3.1.0-preview2.19528.8" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.0-preview2.19528.8" />
```

I have even followed Microsoft's example for [Use WS-Federation without ASP.NET Core Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/ws-federation?view=aspnetcore-3.1#use-ws-federation-without-aspnet-core-identity), but with no luck.

Comment: I'm right up to hear as well :)

Answer (score 5):

This I an older post, but still pops up first in Google for me so..

I had more or less arrived at the same issue. The OP's post in this thread helped me:

[Blazor - Securing using ADFS with local DB repository: how/when to hook into SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59108861/blazor-securing-using-adfs-with-local-db-repository-how-when-to-hook-into-sql)

More specifically, the middleware added to Configure() method made a difference. I ended up with this in my solution:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    ClaimsPrincipal user = context.User;

    if (!user.Identities.Any(x => x.IsAuthenticated))
    {
       await context.ChallengeAsync(WsFederationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    if (next != null)
    {
       await next().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
});
```

Comment: This concept worked great. To make it work with latest Blazor version as of today, I had to do _ChallengeRequest_ like this *await Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions.ChallengeAsync(context, WsFederationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).ConfigureAwait(false);*